# Side effect in thread-local static

Tags: rust

This code

```
#![feature(thread_local)]

#[thread_local]
pub static FOO: [&str; 1] = [ "Hello" ];

fn change_foo(s: &'static str) {
    FOO[0] = s;
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", FOO[0]);
    change_foo("Test");
    println!("{}", FOO[0]);
}
```

produces behavior I expect in debug:

```
Hello
Test
```

but in release, it produces:

```
Hello
Hello
```

(tested in the playground, I have no Rust compiler on hand for now).

But, in release, if I print the value in the function:

```
#![feature(thread_local)]

#[thread_local]
pub static FOO: [&str; 1] = [ "Hello" ];

fn change_foo(s: &'static str) {
    print!("");
    FOO[0] = s;
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", FOO[0]);
    change_foo("Test");
    println!("{}", FOO[0]);
}
```

the output is ok.

Why is this happening? Is the optimization too aggressive?

Comment: This seems like a bug, I suggest reporting it on the [issue tracking the stabilization of this feature](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/29594).

If you need to use `thread_local`, I suggest using the [macro instead](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.thread_local.html)

Comment: Well, the program doesn't compile with [Integer32's playground](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=d73b7eda888ec449d12dc5b259da0b4c&version=nightly), although it does compile and run at [play.rust-lang.org](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=c87d1ced47d6b76acfd3fc6daf90ce34&version=nightly). This is probably a bug which has already been fixed.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I will delete this question.

Comment: Wait! An answer that effectively points to a known bug and its fix can still be a good Q/A.

Comment: @E_net4 When I am at home, I will test with the last nightly version.

Comment: @E_net4 Actually, I tried with the last version of the nightly compiler and the bug is still there. I will report it in github.